# When did the idea of macros (user-defined code transformation) appear?

Tags: macros, lisp, scheme, history, racket

I have read McCarthy's 1960 paper on LISP and found no reference to anything that's similar to user-defined macros or normal order evaluation. I was wondering when macros first appeared in programming language history (and also in Lisp history):

- When was the idea of user-defined code transformation (before interpretation or compilation) first described (theoretically)?
- What was the first programming language implementation to have Lisp-like macros (by "Lisp-like" I mean "using a readable Turing-complete language to do code-transformation")? (including non-Lisps -- Forth for example is quite old, but I'm not sure if the first Forth implementation already had "IMMEDIATE")
- Also which of those was the first high-level programming language (exclude assembler languages...)
- What was the first Lisp dialect to have macros?

Thank you!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Macro_(computer_science)#Early_Lisp_macros https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fexpr

Answer (score 10, accepted):

From [The Evolution of Lisp](http://www.dreamsongs.com/Files/HOPL2-Uncut.pdf) (PDF) (Steele/Gabriel):

> 3.3 Macros
>
> Macros appear to have been introduced into Lisp by Timothy P. Hart in 1963 in a short MIT AI Memo [Hart, 1963],

See:

MIT AI Memo 57, Timothy P. Hart, [MACRO Definitions for LISP](http://bitsavers.informatik.uni-stuttgart.de/pdf/mit/ai/aim/AIM-057.pdf), October 1963

Comment: The first link is dead.

Comment: @jcubic: I have fixed the link

Answer (score 18):

To look for how macros where introduced into Lisp, you should look for mentions of *FEXPRs* and *FSUBRs* which the predecessors of modern Lisp macros (or more accurately, *FEXPRs* are the predecessors of user-defined macros).  These are mentioned in several places -- for example, in the [From LISP 1 to LISP 1.5](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/history/lisp/node4.html) section of McCarthy's [History of Lisp](http://www-formal.stanford.edu/jmc/history/lisp/lisp.html).  But in fact, it's also mentioned earlier than that: in p.48 of the [LISP I PROGRAMMER'S MANUAL](http://history.siam.org/sup/Fox_1960_LISP.pdf) (from 1960) you can see a description of FEXPRs and FSUBRs.

BTW, it's a little bogus to compare Lisp macros with string-based systems.  The advantage of using a tree transformer vs string manipulations is significant enough to make it a completely different system.  Another important aspect of Lisp macros is that they are *local* transformation vs a global program transformation (the most obvious paper to read for this is Felleisen's [On the Expressive Power of Programming Languages](http://www.ccs.neu.edu/scheme/pubs/scp91-felleisen.ps.gz)).  And of course there's a whole area here -- going from FEXPRs to the modern, more well behaved macros, then to hygienic macros in Scheme (which deal with a representation that is richer than symbolic parse trees), then a combination of macros and a module system, syntax expansion phases, etc etc etc.  There's probably enough stuff here for a few years of reading...

Answer (score 11):

I think the idea goes back to [Post systems](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_canonical_system), rewriting with strings ("if you see this string, replace it with that string").  Post systems are Turing-capable, and can thus compute anything (including program texts!).  Emil Post's paper on these is dated 1943, but supposedly he did the original conceptualization in the 1920s.

[The General Purpose Macro Processor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_purpose_macro_processor), one of the first widely used ones, was available in the early 60s.

[TRAC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/TRAC_programming_language) is another early macro processor dating to the same period.  The [History of Computer Languages (TRAC)](http://hopl.murdoch.edu.au/showlanguage.prx?exp=276&language=TRAC) says it was designed in 1959.

Both of these are Turing-capable macro processors.

[SNOBOL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SNOBOL) also dates from the same period.

The fact that very general-purpose macro processors were being built in the early 60s hints to me that there were likely special-purpose macro processors built before then to provide inspiration. I'm pretty sure macro processors were in use in assemblers before this point, but I don't have specific evidence.

I know that COBOL has so-called COPY libs, which are a cross between macros and include files.  I don't know when this was introduced into COBOL, but the langauge goes back to 1958.

It is interest to note that LISP macros can be considered to be a special case of tree-to-tree rewrites ("if you see an s-expression that looks like this, replace it by an s-expression that looks like that").   Trees can be easily modelled as strings (see: "LISP" :) and thus LISP macros are a special case of string rewriting.

The generalized case of tree-rewriting is now the basis for [Program Transformation Systems](http://www.semanticdesigns.com/Products/DMS/ProgramTransformation.html), which can carry out massive changes on program text.

Comment: Thanks -- I had forgotten about assembler macros and Post systems. This is very useful -- and I'll also edit my question to include "the first high-level language" -- which is not yet clear if it was COBOL or not.